# How to append url using rewrite?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

When user visited my website `www.abc.com`, I would like to make it to be `www.abc.com\xx\yy\zz.html`. However if user visited anything other than `www.abc.com`, the url should remain the same.

Expected:

`www.abc.com` => `www.abc.com\xx\yy\zz.html`

`www.abc.com\xx` => `www.abc.com\xx`

`www.abc.com?hello=123` => `www.abc.com?hello=123`

I know I should use `rewrite` and `redirect` to achieve this but I'm not sure how to conditionally check for above situation

Comment: Can you check for `^$` ? I'm looking [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) but unsure of exact implementation. Something along the lines of `rewrite ^$ /xx/yy/zz.html` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
rewrite ^/$ /xx/yy/zz.html;
```

This should match the root URL and rewrite to `/xx/yy/zz.html`.